# A German word for non-alcoholic, carbonated, sweet drinks?

Tags: single-word-request

Is there a German word for soft drinks, i.e. the group of non-alcoholic, carbonated, sweet drinks?

It should cover Cola, Fanta and Sprite, but not mineral water, squash or beer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the whole german language area **[Softdrink](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softdrink)** is an established loanword, **[Limonade](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limonade)** is the longer established word, although its based on the itialian *limonata* (lemon water) and can be originated to the persian *laimun* meaning lemon.
**Limonade** lets you expect natural integrients, but this differs for regions and for types (nobody would expect natural sprite, but *Orangenlimonade* should be made with real oranges contrary to *Fanta*).
As far as I know *Coke* is included in *Softdrinks*, can be meant with *Brause* but won't be meant with *Limonade*. The most usual expression for *Coke* is simply **Cola** or the respective trademark (Coca-Cola, Pepsi (Cola), Afri-Cola, ...)

Especially in Germany, particularly northern and eastern Germany the term **[Brause](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brause)** is a common word. Brause is used to describe artificially made integrients. In eastern germany however its synonymous with **Limonade**.

Alternatively there is **[Schorle](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schorle)** used at least in the Ruhr area down to Baden-Württemberg. Schorle is usually used to describe a juice mixed with sparkling water. It's also used for alcoholic drinks like **Weinschorle**, but then the alcohol is included in the name.

In Bavaria and Austria (except Vorarlberg) the word **[Kracherl](http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-1009-reise-at-Kracherl.html)** is used. But in the area of Upper Austria, Salzburg and Styria it became less used in the last ten years but should be understood good.

In Southern Tyrolean none of these words are used, instead they use the italian **aranciata**. **Limonade** may be used, but only for lemon water. Thanks @splattne for pointing this out in the comments.

After being reminded by takkat: **Sprudel** is a word usually used in Germany for sparkling water, but in Baden-Württemberg for **Limonade**. Beware of extra hints like *süßer Sprudel* or *Sprudel gelb/weiß*.
For Vorarlberg/Baden-Württemberg (alemannic region) I don't know an other word than Softdrink.

Although **Limonade** has a highly spread it doesn't allow for usage everywhere. So the answer to your question is **No**, there isn't a single word. Regardless I'd always try to start with **Limonade** or the tradmarks *Cola, Fanta, Sprite*, thats what gives the best chances.

Comment: In Baden-Württemberg the term *[süsser] Sprudel [weiß/gelb]* or *Schorle* is  used rather than Softdrink.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. Heard both of them. Schorle also in the Ruhrgebiet, but didn't remember.

Comment: "Baden-Württemberg", not "Badem" (cannot edit for just one character)  And Schorle... I didn't know they use that in the Ruhrgebiet too, I thought (and still suspect) it's a more southern term.

Comment: I heard it in Cologne and more into the Ruhrgebiet too. So if nobody else objects. Thx 4 proof reading.

Comment: The correct Italian word for lemonade is *limonata*, not *lemonata*.

Comment: Nice answer. Since I'm from South Tyrol: we **don't use** Brause, Limonade (only for lemon water), Sprudel, Kracherl; actually we don't have a precise common word for this kind of beverage. There's one thing worth mentioning: we use the Italian word *aranciata* for drinks like Fanta.

Comment: thanks for your info splattne, I'll work it into the answer.

Comment: "Softdrink" is an abomination, but you have to admit that as such the word nicely matches the actual things. Am passendsten ist "Zuckerwasser".

Comment: Ich know Zuckerwasser but there isn't an entry in Wikipedia, Wiktionary nor Ostarrichi. Additionally my meta search engine seems to be down. I'll try to add that info after I know the etymology of Zuckerwasser.

Comment: Can't say I've heard "Softdrink" used in common German... "Brause" does not *describe* artificial ingredients (though it does come with that association) - the word only *describes* the sparkling aspect. In the area where I'm from (near Bremen), "Sprudel" would seem to be the most fitting - but it does also seem to sound slightly dated.

Comment: "Sprudel is a word usually used in Germany for sparkling water, but in Baden-Württemberg for Limonade." - to someone living in BW, this sounds wrong, and it also does not quite match what Takkat said. *Sprudel* still means carbonated water also in BW, it's just "süßer Sprudel" (or, maybe alternatively, although I had never heard of these terms, "Sprudel weiß/gelb") that means lemonade.

Comment: With that said, *Schorle* would definitely not be used for coke or Fanta or anything like that in my experience, especially considering that it is usually used as a compound, such as "Apfel[saft]schorle", "Orangen[saft]schorle", "Saftschorle", etc.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know how *exact* the word is, but the term *Brause* is typically used for this. It's another (older) word for *Limonade* (also used often), and e.g. when talking to children one often refers to Sprite and Fanta als *weiße* resp. *gelbe Brause*.

*Brause* may be colloquial though and is not exactly the same as *Limonade*, but is actually part of the food law as a *Verkehrsbezeichnung*, i.e. an official name for a kind of drink. Colloquially, *Limonade* is often shortened to *Limo* (pronounced *Limmo*).

Thanks to Pekka and bernd_k for pointing these out.

In everyday life, there will not be much difference between these terms. Technically, however, Brause may also include artificial flavors and colors, while Limonade may not.

There is also the term *Erfrischungsgetränk*, though that is not necessarily excluding non-sweet drinks and not necessarily carbonated.

Comment: So Cola is also _Limonade_, even though it doesn't taste of citrus?

Comment: I think in today's use of the word, yes. Fanta also doesn't taste like orange. Now that you say it, I think there's another word which I'm adding to my answer. Wikipedia says: "Zu den Limonaden gehören auch die coffeinhaltigen Colagetränke und die meisten Energy-Drinks."

Comment: +1. *Brause* is not only colloquial though, it is a part of food law and is the closest match: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brause in daily life, *Limonade* may be the best choice - it is usually understood that Coca-Cola and the likes are included.

Comment: In spoken speech _Limonade_ is often shortend to _Limmo_ .

Comment: @Pekka: In the linked article, there is *Cola-Brausepulver* as an example, so I guess Brause also includes Coca-Cola.

Comment: @Oregon yeah, *Brause* is a perfect match, but not as well-known and common as *Limonade*.

Comment: *Brause* will not necessarily be understood in southern parts of Germany, *Limonade* will. For us southerners *Brause* is used for the thing to take a shower...

Comment: @Takkat: Good catch. Though this is kind of strange if Brause is a *Verkehrsbezeichnung* :) In the North, you'll also use it for the shower thing though. But most people in a restaurant or wherever will typically know that you're not asking for a shower when ordering *Brause*. Should try this in Southern Germany though... ;)

Comment: @Takkat: I'd typically only ask for a *Brause* when being asked what I want to drink, so it's rather the same as in a restaurant. Interesting situation though ;)

Comment: Funny findings, guys. All true. +1 on this answer.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, Limonade does not at all include being citrus based - it could be any fruit (for example, cherry and woodruff are common).

Comment: Hmm, when I hear "Brause" I think of something where I have to pour some sort of powder into clear water... (also see "Brausetablette"). And I don't think I have ever heard it used for ordering in restaurants either. I also cannot confirm that it would be commonly understood [to generally mean "softdrinks"] in Northern Germany. If pressed, I'd have placed it more to the East...

Comment: @Oliver Giesen: It's not commonly understand to generally mean softdrinks in Northern Germany. It's only for some kinds. But I think I never encountered a restaurant here where *Brause* would not be understood.

Comment: @OregonGhost : Yes, it would very definitely be understood. I'm only kind of objecting to the idea that this word is typical for Northen Germany.

Comment: @Oliver Giesen: I wouldn't have thought that as well - but look at all the Southern Germans thinking *shower* when you say *Brause* ;)

Comment: "Brause" is old fashioned in some parts of germany, you'd probably be sold a showerhead or hosepipe attachment instead of a drink :)

Comment: Brause ist für mich Pulver, das man erst in Wasser auflösenn muss. Dürfte regional sein. Eine Bekannte aus Sachen benutzte es und meinte das, was bei mir (Rheinland) unter Limo lief. Ich hab mich gefragt, warum sie das Pulverzeug will.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the excellent answers, in many restaurants' menus, you'll find these drinks under *Alkoholfreie Getränke* (non-alcoholic beverages), often together with water, but separate from juices and hot drinks.

Answer (score 5):

I'll add an Austrian/Bavarian expression for completness:

> [Kracherl](http://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kracherl)
>
> A Kracherl (áá Limo oda Limonad) is a sias Dringa, des aus Wåssa, Zucka, Gschmå und Koinsaire gmacht werd.

Caution: Link points to the [Bavarian Wikipedia](http://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptseitn) domain.

Answer (score 4):

to give a short answer, German differentiates between alcoholic (alkoholische Getränke) and non-alcoholic Drinks (alkoholfreie Getränke). Non-alcoholic drinks are further categorized in cold (Erfrischungsgetränke/Kaltgetränke) and hot drinks (Heißgetränke).

Carbonated drinks with flavor are generally called "Limonade". You may accentuate the flavor by adding its noun to the name, like "Zitronenlimonade" or "Orangenlimonade". You may also prefer a more formal way to name your drink, like "Kohlensäurehaltiges Erfrischungsgetränk" (as big-players do: http://www.cceag.de/kundenservice/produkte/kohlensaeurehaltige-erfrischungsgetraenke/). It depends heavily on what you're willing to say.

Answer (score 3):

Mir fallen die Begriffe **Softgetränk** oder **Softdrink** sowie **Erfrischungsgetränk**
ein. Dazu zählen streng genommen aber auch Getränke, die nicht unbedingt süß oder kohlensäurehaltig sind.

Ein [Online-Hotel-Lexikon hat folgende Beschreibung für das Wort](http://hotel-lexikon.wikia.com/wiki/Softgetr%C3%A4nke):

> Ein Softdrink ist ein alkoholfreies Getränk. Auch die Mischungen aus alkoholfreien Getränken werden als solche bezeichnet.
>
> Softdrinks werden in folgende Gruppen unterteilt:
>
> - Wasser
> - Fruchtsäfte, Fruchtnektare
> - Gemüsesäfte, Gemüsenektare
> - Erfrischungsgetränke
> - Fruchtsaftgetränke
> - Limonaden
> - Brausen
> - Mineralstoffgetränke (z.B. isotonische Getränke)
> - Diät- Erfrischungsgetränke
> - Brennwertverminderte (light) Erfrischungsgetränke

Comment: Soft heißt aber einfach nur kein Alkohol, oder? Das ist dann schon ein sehr weit darüber liegender Sammelbegriff.

Comment: @OregonGhost Ja, das stimmt. Vielleicht hatte ich das so im Kopf, weil die meisten Erfrischungsgetränke/Softdrinks süß und kohlensäurehaltig sind...

Comment: Ich hätte so aus dem Kopf auch nicht Gemüsesäfte erwartet, obwohl's natürlich irgendwie Sinn ergibt :)

Comment: Das nächste Mal beim Bestellen: *"Haben Sie Softdrinks?"* - *"Ja"* -  *"Dann bitte einen mit Wasser aufgespritzten brennwertverminderten Diät-Gemüsenektar"*